# automatic typing of nested lists

Tags: haskell

While working through Richard Bird's *Thinking Functionally With Haskell*, I came across a demonstration of Haskell's type system that I find puzzling (p. 44):

> `[ [], [[]], [[[]]] ] :: [[[[a]]]]`
>
> To explain, let the main list have type `[b]`. The first element is a
>   list, so `b=[c]`. The second element is a list of lists, so `c=[d]`. The
>   third element is a list of lists of lists, so `d=[a]`

Doesn't this type signature indicate that the first element of the main list has type `[[[a]]]`? I don't see how that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's rewrite this:

```
l = [l1, l2, l3]
 where l1 = []
       l2 = [[]]
       l3 = [[[]]]
```

Now we assign type variables: ab initio

```
       l1 :: b
       l2 :: b
       l3 :: b
```

since they all have to have the same type, so `l` has some type `[b]`. Now, more specifically,

```
       l1 :: [c]
       l2 :: [[d]]
       l3 :: [[[e]]]
```

to justify the number of brackets. But these still have to be the same type `b`, i.e. in fact

```
       l1 :: [[[e]]]
       l2 :: [[[e]]]
       l3 :: [[[e]]]
```

and

```
l = [ [] :: [[[e]]]
    , [[]] :: [[[e]]]
    , [[[]]] :: [[[e]]] ]
```

which as a whole has type `[[[[e]]]]`. Or, if you prefer, `[[[[a]]]]`.

---

Perhaps it all gets clearer if you consider more interesting specific examples. The following are `[Int]` lists:

- `[1,2,3]`
- `[1]`
- `[0]`
- `[]`

These are `[[Int]]` lists:

- `[ [1,2], [1,2,3] ]`
- `[ [1], [2] ]`
- `[ [1], [] ]`
- `[ [] ]`
- `[ ]`

And these are `[[[Int]]]` lists:

- `[ [[1]], [[2],[]], [[3],[],[]] ]`
- `[ [[]], [[1]], [[2,3]] ]`
- `[ [], [[]] ]`
- `[ [[]] ]`
- `[ ]`

Note that the empty list `[]` is possible for all types. The list containing only an empty list, `[[]]` is possible for `[[Int]]` and `[[[Int]]]`, and the list containing a list with only an empty list needs a doubly-nested list `[[[Int]]]`.

Comment: I lose you at the move from step 3 to 4. If I put a single integer into these nested lists (e.g., [ [1],[[2]] ]), the compiler no longer accepts it. Therefore, how can they have the same type?

Comment: The compiler no longer accepts it because `[1]` and `[[2]]` can _not_ have the same type (e.g. `[Int]` vs. `[[Int]]`). OTOH, `[]` and `[[]]` can both have type `[[Int]]`, i.e. both lists of lists: the former is the empty list (containing no lists) and the latter is a _non-empty_ list, containing one list – though that in turn contains no integers (but could).